# How can I use one lvmcache "cache pool LV" for multiple origin LVs?

Tags: linux, partitioning, raid, cache, lvm

I have a shiny new computer with a not-that-large SSD (120GB) and two gigantic spinning-rust HDs (3TB each).  I want to partition it as follows:

- swap (~128GB), operating system (~128GB), and data (all the rest) partitions striped across the HDs
- tiny boot partition on the SSD
- all the rest of the SSD's space is used for a cache pool
- the cache pool should be shared among all of the HD partitions, except maybe not the swap

I tried to do this with lvmcache and ran into the following problems:

- If you just create a cache pool in the obvious way (as described e.g. [here](https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2014/05/22/using-lvms-new-cache-feature/)) you can only assign that to cache a *single* origin LV.  So I could have it for the OS or for the data, but not both.
- I tried to work around that by creating a "thin pool" spanning all of the HDs, thinking that I could cache the entire thin pool, then assign OS and data LVs out of that, but got told that it is not possible to cache a thin pool.  (The `lvmthin` manpage doesn't make a hell of a lot of sense, it is possible that I did that part wrong.)

I am out of ideas.  Can anyone suggest how to make this work?  Note that I am not married to lvm, if bcache+plain MD (for the striping) can do this, or some other tool I don't know about, then that would be Just Fine Too.

Answer (score 3):

You can create cached volume and convert it to thin-pool.

cache pool (cache data + cache metadata) -> cached volume (cache pool + original big slow volume) -> cached thin-pool

In this example vg0 is your volume group with physical volumes /dev/small-fast-disk and /dev/big-slow-disk. All logical volumes must be in the same volume group.

## create cachepool volume (cache data and cache metadata in one command)

```
lvcreate --type cache-pool --name cachepool --size 128G vg0 /dev/smal-fast-disk
```

## create cache volume

```
lvcreate --type cache --cachepool vg0/cachepool --size 3T --name thincachevol vg0 /dev/big-slow-disk
```

## convert cached volume to thin volume

```
lvconvert --thinpool vg0/thincachevol
```

Comment: How is this done?  Provide detailed instructions.

Comment: Creating the to-be-cached volumes in a thin pool may not be what the OP wants because it adds fragmentation and creates the risk of getting full while `df` still shows free space. This is risky and hard to manage.

Answer (score 3):

On a mainline kernel using the same cache for multiple origin devices is NOT supported by dm-cache (which is what lvmcache uses underneath) due to races accessing metadata. See [Re: [dm-devel] dm-cache: can the same cache be used with multiple origin devices?](https://www.redhat.com/archives/dm-devel/2013-July/msg00113.html) for a 2013 comment from a developer.

However, for completeness the [original dm-cache developer has an abandoned testing repo supports "multiple source devices on the same cache device"](https://github.com/mingzhao/dm-cache/tree/master/testing/shared-cache) (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dm-cache/q-lM1t438PU for details) but this code is not in mainline kernels.